# Collapsing four data frame columns into two, interleaved columns

Tags: r, tidyr, r-leaflet

I am using latitude and longitude data to draw lines on a `leaflet` map (see below). Ideally the lines would be stored in `lat` and `lng` columns in a data frame. In the `lat` column, each starting point lat value would be followed by an ending point lat value, then by the starting point lat value for another line (the `line_id` column allows each line to be distinguished). The `lng` data is arranged similarly. Ideally the data frame should look like this:

```
> df.better
  line_id      lat        lng
1     ABC 51.50995 -0.1345093
2     ABC 51.51074 -0.1345093
3     XYZ 51.50991 -0.1345193
4     XYZ 51.51079 -0.1351200
```

The problem is that it comes out of the data store in this format:

```
> df.wide
  line_id start_lat  end_lat  start_lng  end_lng
1     ABC  51.50995 51.51074 -0.1345093 -0.13519
2     XYZ  51.50991 51.51079  0.1351900  0.13512
```

This looks a bit like the classic "wide to long" data wrangling problem, for which there are many questions and answers, but a standard "long" format collapses the lat and lng data into one column, and I need two columns. I have tried a tidyverse solution as follows:

```
df2 <- df.wide %>% pivot_longer(cols = start_lat:end_lng,
                         names_to="variable",
                         values_to="value")
```

Then I clean up the `variable` column:

```
df2$variable <- gsub(".*_lat","lat",df2$variable)
df2$variable <- gsub(".*_lng","lng",df2$variable)
```

This is the result, which at least seems to have the data in the right order:

```
> df2
A tibble: 8 x 3
  line_id variable      value
  <fct>   <chr>         <dbl>
1 ABC     lat      51.50995  
2 ABC     lat      51.51074  
3 ABC     lng      -0.1345093
4 ABC     lng      -0.13519  
5 XYZ     lat      51.50991  
6 XYZ     lat      51.51079  
7 XYZ     lng       0.13519  
8 XYZ     lng       0.135120
```

The final step would seem to involve spreading the data again, but using `pivot_wider` results in a complaint about values not being uniquely identified:

```
df2 %>% pivot_wider(names_from = variable,values_from = value)
    # A tibble: 2 x 3
      line_id         lat         lng
      <fct>   <list<dbl>> <list<dbl>>
    1 ABC             [2]         [2]
    2 XYZ             [2]         [2]
    Warning message:
Values in `value` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
```

I can (I think) see why the error occurs, but providing unique identifiers in `variable` just takes me back to where I started. How can/should I approach this?

```
require(magrittr)
require(tidyr)
require(dplyr)

options(pillar.sigfig = 7)

df.better <- data.frame(
  line_id = c("ABC","ABC","XYZ","XYZ"),
  lat = c(51.509950,51.510736,51.509910,51.510786),
  lng = c(-0.1345093,-0.1345093,-0.1345193,-0.135120)
)

df.wide <- data.frame(
  line_id = c("ABC","XYZ"),
  start_lat = c(51.509950,51.509910),
  end_lat = c(51.510736,51.510786),
  start_lng = c(-0.1345093,0.135190),
  end_lng = c(-0.135190,0.135120)
)

df2 <- df.wide %>% pivot_longer(cols = start_lat:end_lng,
                         names_to="variable",
                         values_to="value")

df2$variable <- gsub(".*_lat","lat",df2$variable)
df2$variable <- gsub(".*_lng","lng",df2$variable)

df2 %>% pivot_wider(names_from = variable,values_from = value)

m <- leaflet() %>% setView(lng = -0.1345093, lat = 51.510090, zoom = 18) %>% addTiles()

for (i in unique(df.better$line_id)) { # HT: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44547502/952708
  m <- m %>%
    addPolylines(data = df.better[df.better$line_id == i, ],
                 lng = ~lng, lat = ~lat, color = "Green",
                 opacity = 0.5, weight = 2, dashArray = 5)
}

m
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for something like this:

```
df.wide <- data.frame(
  line_id = c("ABC","XYZ"),
  start_lat = c(51.509950,51.509910),
  end_lat = c(51.510736,51.510786),
  start_lng = c(-0.1345093,0.135190),
  end_lng = c(-0.135190,0.135120)
)

df.wide %>% 
  pivot_longer(-line_id,
               names_to = c("set", ".value"),
               names_pattern = "(.+)_(.+)"
  )

#  line_id set        lat        lng
#  <fct>   <chr>    <dbl>      <dbl>
#1 ABC     start 51.50995 -0.1345093
#2 ABC     end   51.51074 -0.13519  
#3 XYZ     start 51.50991  0.13519  
#4 XYZ     end   51.51079  0.135120
```

Answer (score 1):

something lke this might do the trick

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table::fread("line_id start_lat  end_lat  start_lng  end_lng
     ABC  51.50995 51.51074 -0.1345093 -0.13519
     XYZ  51.50991 51.51079  0.1351900  0.13512")

dt.melt <- melt( dt, 
                 id.vars = "line_id", 
                 measure.vars = patterns( lon = "_lng$", 
                                          lat = "_lat$" ), 
                 variable.name = "point_id" )

#    line_id point_id        lon      lat
# 1:     ABC        1 -0.1345093 51.50995
# 2:     XYZ        1  0.1351900 51.50991
# 3:     ABC        2 -0.1351900 51.51074
# 4:     XYZ        2  0.1351200 51.51079

library( sf )
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
dt.points <- st_as_sf( dt.melt, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)

dt.lines <- dt.points %>%
  group_by( line_id ) %>%
  summarise( geometry = st_combine( geometry ) ) %>%
  st_cast( "LINESTRING" )

leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addPolylines( data = dt.lines, popup = ~line_id )
```

[image]

Comment: Not really a `data.table` user but appreciated the fully worked answer.